# Closest highest value in array with multiple columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, math

I want to test an acumulated value (`var goal`) from some input fields with the closest **highest** value`['size']` in an array.

So let's say my goal is to find the highest closest value to `size 95`.

```
var variants = [
          { value: "128428226", size: "50 ", price: 3.72, priceIncl: 4.5 },
          { value: "128428229", size: "100 ", price: 5.5, priceIncl: 6.65 },
          { value: "128428232", size: "150 ", price: 7.27, priceIncl: 8.8 }
    ]

var goal = 95; 
var closest = variants;
var closestPrice = '';
var closestPriceIncl = '';
var closestVal = '';


 $.each(variants, function(){
          if (closest['size'] == null || Math.abs(this['size'] - goal) < Math.abs(closest['size'] - goal)) { 
            closest = this;
            closestPrice = closest['price'];
            closestPriceIncl = closest['priceIncl'];
            closestVal = closest['value']
          }
        });
```

I'm able to get all values I want. However when the goal is something like `75` then my script selects the values from `size: "50"`. So actually when the goal is 51 it should select 100 etc.

I really can't find a way to do that. I found some other answers which use a function but then I don't get how to get the other values. 
(Simply I need to find the closest highest value.)
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: shot in the dark here, `closest = variants[this.index+1];`

Comment: @admcfajn: I don't think so. When value is 95 it selects 150 instead of 100 which is the closest highest value.

Comment: okay, here's a place where it could be improved: `var closest = variants;` followed by `closest = this;` might not be a good idea. If I'm not mistaken you're taking a variable that is all your data and re-assigning it as one of it's own children. a new variable would be better for that (imho). I'll try to have a peek later, but should get back to work. and a `for(var item in variants)` loop might be a better way to go, just my own preference though.

Comment: @admcfajn: You might be true there :) However above code works as should except that it sometimes selects lowest nearest value instead of highest nearest. But your true code wise can be better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, the following code should be sufficient:

```
    var variants = [
    { value: "128428226", size: "50 ", price: 3.72, priceIncl: 4.5 },
    { value: "128428229", size: "100 ", price: 5.5, priceIncl: 6.65 },
    { value: "128428232", size: "150 ", price: 7.27, priceIncl: 8.8 }
];

var goal = 51;

var closest = null ;
var minDiff = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
for(var index in variants){
    var valueObject = variants[index];
    if(valueObject.size > goal){
        var diff = Math.abs(valueObject.size - goal);
        if(diff < minDiff){
            closest = valueObject;
            minDiff = diff;
        }
    }
}
console.log(minDiff);
console.log(closest);
```

The two defining predicates being that the closest variant have a size greater than the goal and that the difference between the sizes should be minimal.

Comment: Exactly!! If you mind to explain... These two -> `var closest = null ; var minDiff = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;` Stil learning so what does it actually do?! I think `null` because you can have value 0 which will return true r something?

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with this. I think this must be you are trying to do.

```js
var variants = [
          { value: "128428226", size: "50 ", price: 3.72, priceIncl: 4.5 },
          { value: "128428229", size: "100 ", price: 5.5, priceIncl: 6.65 },
          { value: "128428232", size: "150 ", price: 7.27, priceIncl: 8.8 }
    ];

var arr = Object.keys(variants).map(function(k) { return parseInt(variants[k]['size']) });

function closest(array,num){
    var i=0;
    var minDiff=1000;
    var ans;
    for(i in array){
         var m=Math.abs(num-array[i]);
         if(m<minDiff){ 
                minDiff=m; 
                ans=array[i]; 
            }
      }
    return ans;
}

console.log(closest(arr,75))
```

Comment: Your answer returns 50 when using 75. User distinctly asks for higher value and even states "So actually when the goal is 51 it should select 100 etc."

Comment: no. If goal is 75, it must return 76 and above. Just as in his example...he has goal of 51...the answer has to be next highest number above goal..which is why he said it should select 100. So your answer should return 100. If you have goal of 101 it should return 150.

Comment: @AdhershMNair: Matt is correct! This returns 50 when it should return 100. I'm looking for highest value. Not lowest since my own script already did that!

Comment: @Matt You mean the closest highest number. Is it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the absolute delta of the elemnt and the previous stire temporary result and if smaller, then push a new array, otherwise check if the delta is the same, then push the actual item to the result set.

As result an array is returned with the closest items.

Maybe it's a good idea and clean the data from appending space of values, like `size: "50 "`.

```js
var variants = [{ value: "128428226", size: "50", price: 3.72, priceIncl: 4.5 }, { value: "128428229", size: "100", price: 5.5, priceIncl: 6.65 }, { value: "128428232", size: "150", price: 7.27, priceIncl: 8.8 }],
    goal = 95,
    closest = variants.reduce(function (r, o) {
        if (!r || Math.abs(o.size - goal) < Math.abs(r[0].size - goal)) {
            return [o];
        }
        if (Math.abs(o.size - goal) === Math.abs(r[0].size - goal)) {
            return r.push(o);
        }
        return r;
    }, undefined);
    
console.log(closest);
```